# Bluetooth Device (RFCOMM Protocol TDI) Driver shows error when bluetooth is manually turned off and then turned ON on windows tablets

Tags: c#, bluetooth, windows-10, rfcomm, spp

Thanks in advance.

We are connecting one device using the bluetooth SPP with Windows tablet as client and the device as server.

We initially pair the device with tablet and then with using SPP we connect to device using serial port. and its works.

But when we manually turn off tablet bluetooth and turn it ON again then it never get connected.

Also in Device manager we are seeing error on Bluetooth Device (RFCOMM Protocol TDI) Driver and we are not seeing any ports in the device manager.

It gets resolved when we restart the tablet.

Please let us know how to resolve this without rebooting the tablet.

Below is the snippet of device manager working and showing error.[image: Error]

[image: working]